# Repeat whole tkinter program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to repeat whole tkinter program after pressing a button? Ways to do it without pressing a button will be cool too.Something like repeating whole mainloop

Comment: What exactly do you mean by repeat? Are you wanting to restart the program?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank not sure if you are being sarcastic or not but it is obvious they are a "new contributor" as they have no points under their name :P

Comment: Yes, i want to restart the program

Comment: When you say you want to restart the program, do you really need to restart the program (ie: recreate all the windows), or do you really just need to reset the state to the starting point (eg: clear all of the input widgets, reset counters, etc)? Sometimes restarting is easiest, but often all you really need to do is reset a couple of widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your comment `Yes, i want to restart the program` the below code will do just that.

I think it is best to build this as a class and manage the restart with a method that also calls an outside function.

First thing we need to do is `destroy` the application and then call a function to recreate it.

As long as the window has focus you can restart with `Control+r` or by using the button.

```
import tkinter as tk


def main():
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is a basic app").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Restart", command=self.restart_app).pack()
        self.bind("<Control-r>", self.restart_app)

    def restart_app(self, event=None):
        self.destroy()
        main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As pointed out by Bryan Oakley in the comments there are often global variables in apps that will persist after you recreate your application. If this is the case you need to make sure you are also resetting those variables to their default state or you can move them into the class to make sure this is done automatically when re-creating the app.

Here is an example of what might happen if you are using a global variable.

In this example we have a global variable called `my_name` and in the app you can change this variable. Once you restart the name does not reset to default but rather keeps what you changed it to.

```
import tkinter as tk


my_name = "Mike"

def main():
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()

class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text="This is a basic app written by {}".format(my_name))
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()

        tk.Button(self, text="Set new name!", command=self.set_new_name).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Restart", command=self.restart_app).pack()
        self.bind("<Control-r>", self.restart_app)

    def set_new_name(self):
        global my_name
        my_name = self.entry.get()
        self.lbl.config(text="This is a basic app written by {}".format(my_name))

    def restart_app(self, event=None):
        self.destroy()
        main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this isn't a complete restart -- any global variables that aren't explicitly reset by the app will persist.

Comment: @BryanOakley are they global though? The app is being created inside of a function and is a local variable at this point right? I was also not aware that a global variable would persist if destroyed. Can you maybe explain a little about that point?

Comment: In this specific example you have no global variables, but real world applications often have global variables. That's especially true for new programmers.

Comment: On that note what would be the drawbacks if using a local variable in a restart like this? I honestly do not know. Is it a memory issue?

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh I think I understand what you meant in your first comment. You mean variables like list or numbers that are in the global outside of the class or tk instance.

Comment: Yes. For example, maybe you have a global counter that starts at zero and is incremented every second. Or a global dictionary that gets modified by the GUI. And so on.

Comment: @BryanOakley got it. I have added that note to my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you very much